# Objects follow each other on a curve path

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, path

Similar question but answer does not work. - [Animating a series of objects along a path independently](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7622/animating-a-series-of-objects-along-a-path-independently)

I am trying to make the human objects (which are seperate objects) all follow each other on a path kind of like the stars in the "Paramount Pictures Intro" like below

[image: paramount pictures intro]

So this is my setup right now
[image: My blender setup]
So I have about 28 people that I need to follow a path.  They will not have moving arms or legs all I need is for all of them to make a nice curvy path around a globe and then end up around the earth in a circle.

When I made one person follow path then tried to offset follow location and follow rotation of object in front of it, did not work.  Also tried both methods in the question above.

Does anyone know how this path can be follow to imitate a similar animation as Paramount Pictures.

Comment: You can create one object that follows a path the way you want by following the instructions on the other page. Then just duplicate the whole set-up as many times as you have objects and change their offsets.

Answer (score 6):

Create your object.

Cerate a curve and shape it to the path you want the other objects to follow.

Make sure they have their origins on the same place.

Select the object and add a **Follow Path** constraint. Set the curve as target. Your object will move to the beginning of the curve. Then animate the offset value to make the object travel along the curve.
[image]

For several object you can use an array modifier and set the number of clones you need on the array.

Then add a curve modifier after the array modifier, selecting the curve as object. Then move the object on the X axis.

[image]

Comment: This seems like it will work, but how can I make the stars(people) all different colors while using array modifier?

Answer (score 4):

[image]You can use a "clamp to" constraint.
This will make the mesh follow the curve when transformed.

Or stick with the curve modifier
[image]

Comment: Can you add more explanation? the images are clear, but if the reader doesn't know how to use these modifiers or constraints, he won't be able to do it.

Comment: words are such a chore though

Comment: Can I add color variation within the array of stars(people) like in my image above..

Comment: yes, if you apply the array modifier (and switch to cycles render) then setup this in the node editor http://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=352092&d=1419776765&thumb=1       and here is a video of something similar in action. https://youtu.be/pau2HJsIF7U?t=5m40s But if you dont want to apply the array modifier then you will need to make a custom texture and do this http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?322015-UV-Map-with-Array-Modifier-Question

Comment: I tried making a gif but it wont really work because its too big https://gfycat.com/UnrealisticDelightfulCoot